# how to make initWithNibName behave like instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, nib, uistoryboard

I'm trying to add a view controller container [library](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController) to the [remail](http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/) email client. The idea is that the view controller container  `presents its child view controllers in two layers. It provides functionality for sliding the top view to reveal the views underneath it.`

In the library description this is the suggested way of attaching a child controllerView to it's parent:

```
if (![self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController 
        isKindOfClass:[MenuViewController class]]) {
    self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController  = 
        [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];
  }
```

where *slidingViewController* is `the top-level instance of the view controller container. With this instance, you can set the view controllers underneath the top view and add panning.`

I'm using xib files, not a storeyboard. so my code looked like this instead:

```
if (![self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController 
        isKindOfClass:[MenuViewController class]]) {
    self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController  =
         [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Menu" bundle:nil];
}
```

but using that code.. I'm getting this error:
`-[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil`

which can be traced to slidingViewController doing the following:
`[self.view insertSubview:_underTopViewController.view atIndex:0];`

looking at the documentation.. I see there is a difference between [instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStoryboard/instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier%3a) and [initWithNibName](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName%3abundle%3a): the former returns an object at all times.. where as the latter only loads `the first time the view controller’s view is accessed`.

**Question:** how do I make an initWithNibName return a loaded viewcontroller object regardless if that view has been visited or not.. similar to instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to trigger it by [just accessing the `view` property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1935566/477878), something like;

```
if (![self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController 
              isKindOfClass:[MenuViewController class]]) 
{
    MenuViewController *vc = 
      [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Menu" bundle:nil];
    [vc view];  // <-- access the view and trigger loading
    self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController  = vc;
}
```